# html absolute elements in relative positioned div tag

Tags: html

I have layout like below :

```
 <div style="margin-top:0%" class="postcell">    


                    <div id="postspantitle" >  
                        <span  class="texts"><?php echo __('Başlık :', 'goldmem');?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postptextdiv" >
                        <input class="postptext" type="text" id="posttitle">
                    </div>

  </div>
```

and the css is like follows :

```
.postcell
{
    position:relative;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:green;   
    border-width:3px;
    margin-top:7%

}

#postspantitle
{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1%;
    left:0%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;   
    border-width:3px;

}

.postptextdiv
{
    margin-top:-1%;
    left:20%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red; 
    border-width:3px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I have many other elements with postcell class div tag as parent. Because the number of postcell div tags are created dynamically and decided by front-end user.

My problem is, as postcell is relatively positioned even if I add these div tags with id=postspantitle and class=postptextdiv, the height of the class=postcell div tag does not change at all. I want to set a background for postcell div tag, so the contents in it can be in these seperate backgrounds. However, as the height does not change as I add into class=postcell, I cant set background to class=postcell div tags, as it will only look as a line. I want to add an image :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1AjK.png

green border are class=postcell

red are the childen of class=postcell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible afaik. You will need to declare the `postpttextdiv` elements as `position: relative` in order to trigger a repaint (resize) of the `postcell` div upon insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the children set to position : absolute and expect them to resize their parent.

That is fundamentally against what position : absolute does.

If you want .postcell to be dynamically sized, all you'll have to do is remove the position : absolute line from its children.

If you have reasons for why you can't do that, then the alternative is to write js that will set the height of each postcell to the height of it's children.

jQuery code example:

```
$(".postcell").each( function() {
    var height = $(this).children("#postspantitle").height() + $(this).children(".postptextdiv").height();
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");
});
```

Comment: Yeah I do know it is fundamentally against it. That is why I asked a question didn't I ? :). Because unless I use absolute, I cant provide what I wanna do. But  thanks for the answer will try it out now.

Comment: Ok the thing is, I am working in wordpress environment, so even if I change this to jQuery(postcell).each , it will not work. I could include jquery externally, i guess then it would work. But I would rather be free from javascript.

Comment: If I remove absolute positioning, then in order to put those 2 children div tags in the same row, I have to make them inline. If I do that, I have to make class=postptext divs "float:right" in order to make every new postcell vertically aligned. That is why I use absolute, so only 1 setting to make them in the same row applies to every new class=postcell div I add. If you have any other suggestion, I would be happy to apply.

Comment: Well in that case. Try this. Set one of the divs to standard positioning, and the other one make absolute. That way you'll have the bigger div to resize it horizontally, and you can still place it wherever on the line, and then you have the absolute which I can place on top whereever